# Class entry requested for an object without PHP class - segfault

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, phalcon

We've recently began seeing segfaults occurring with the following crash message:

> Class entry requested for an object without PHP class in
>   .../StatementTransformer.php on line 140

The error occurs intermittently and I'm unable to recreate it. Seems to occur more frequently with load.

The code looks like this:

```
136.    if (!property_exists($response, 'Transactions')) {
137.        return;
138.    }
139.
140.    foreach ($response->Transactions as $transactions) {
           // [...]
148.    }
```

`$response` is an instance of `StdClass` representing a `SOAP` response.

We're using `PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22` and `Phalcon 1.3.1`.

I believe the following bug report is what we're seeing, though I'm not sure: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65928

Comment: I don't have anything useful to add, but damn, good luck with this one -.-